# Trying to generate .ipa file and getting these errors

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios, ipa

Trying to generate ipa file but getting these errors.kindly help me to tackle them.I'm adding the developer account credentials and I've checked Automatically signing
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/08IVH.png

Answer (score 0):

Try run `pod deintegrate && pod install` inside your ios folder.